# OnAuthorization Method of AuthorizationFilterAttribute will execute every time when request arrives?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am writing Web API ( v2.2 ) for accessing another REST API. Reason is that I want restrict some functional and provide more friendly data. In short I am writing wrapper for some REST API. 
I am providing authentication/authorization via my Implementation of `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`. Here is snippet of code:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var authorizeHeader = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;
    if (authorizeHeader != null
        && authorizeHeader.Scheme.Equals("basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        && String.IsNullOrEmpty(authorizeHeader.Parameter) == false)
    {
      // Code to test is username/password correct for second API 
      // Trying to get some recourse with provided credentials
      // ...
    }
}
```

Now I want to understand, if I set my `attribute` to controller's action, like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{taskId}/{dispatchId}")]
[SecureResourceAttribute] // This is my attribute
public IHttpActionResult GetDispatch(string taskId, string dispatchId)
```

Every time when I request this action, `OnAuthorization` method will execute ? Does it anywhere store that client is already authorized ?
If No, how can I get it to store that client is already authorized ?

Thank you, for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: Is OnAuthorization going to be called on every call?

A: If controller is decorated with [Authorize] attribute, Yes.

Q: Does it anywhere store that client is already authorized?

A: No. The service is Stateless by default.

Q: If No, how can I get it to store that client is already authorized?

A: This again goes back to the fact that WEB API Service is stateless and there is no relationship between different requests that comes in.

Comment: Np, Ah we share the same name! Cool